$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$. Is $f(n)+69n$ injective?
$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$.
$f(n)$ is not an injective function.
$$f(1) = f(2)$$
$f(n) + n$ is not an injective function.
$$f(4) + 4 = f(5) + 5$$
$f(n) + 2n$ is not an injective function.
$$f(16) + 2\cdot 16 = f(22) + 2 \cdot 22$$
$f(n) + 3n$ is not an injective function.
$$f(8) + 3\cdot 8 = f(9) + 3 \cdot 9$$
Question:
Is $f(n) + 69n$ an injective function?
My progress:
For all integer $b$ greater than or equal to -62 and less than or equal to 68:
$f(n) + b \cdot n$ is not an injective function.
I found counterexamples for all 131 cases.
I created an algorithm to brute-force search counterexamples that used this: https://oeis.org/A000001/b000001.txt
I used only small values of $n$ in my initial research ($n < 2048$).
All pair of counterexamples that I found are in this interval.
Maybe someone could prove that $f(n) + b \cdot n$ is not injective for all integer $b$. I don't know how to do it.
I know how to find $f(n)$ for some values greater than 2048, but it is complicated.

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151491/number-of-isomorphism-types-of-finite-groups

Could you change to a more descriptive and informative title?

$f(n) + 69n$ is not an injective function.
$$f(3408) + 69 \cdot 3408 = 235322$$
$$f(3410) + 69 \cdot 3410 = 235322$$
Let $b$ an integer.
If $-379 \leq b \leq 379$, then $f(n) + b \cdot n$ is not an injective function.
